# Compiling Petstore 2

Tags: java

I downloaded the sources for Sun's Petstore demo from here - http://java.net/projects/petstore
The big question is how to compile the whole thing. The documentation seems out of date and the ant build files seem to be in a big mess. Has anyone managed to build the current code? Or is there an alternative location where I can download the code (with more up to date build scripts)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the petstore app is outdated and I remember it being around in Sun days. I suggest you look for more up-to-date examples.

Comment: Any suggestions? What I am looking for is a simple JPA webapp. It does not have to be J2EE necessarily. However, it should be under some form of open source license, so that I can use it in a demo and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out kitchensink from the JBoss AS example project was all I needed - https://github.com/jbossas/quickstart